# Add text to the end of specific file

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I want to add a text (sample) to the end of specific file Before the Extension (in powershell or anything else)

for example:
file1.mp4 => file1(sample).mp4 ///
file2.mkv => file2(sample).mkv ///
and don't do anything on other formats

tried this

```
Get-ChildItem *.mp4 | ForEach-Object {
    Rename-Item -Path $_.Name -NewName "$($_.Name) (sample)$($_.extension)" 
}
```

but it adds an addition file format to the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `.Name` includes the extension. Try `.BaseName` which does not, e.g.:

```
-NewName "$($_.BaseName) (sample)$($_.extension)"
```